# Producing wrong XML output

Tags: java, xmlhttprequest

Attached are two screen shots, and my code. I am trying to get the animation_sequence as a closing and ending bracket, I've tried my best but now I seek your help. Please help. The code I have produces it as a

Code:

```
 DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document testDoc = builder.parse(new File("./data/sprite_types/" + spriteName + "/" + spriteName + ".xml"));
        Element state = testDoc.createElement("state");
        state.setTextContent(element);
        Element animationState = testDoc.createElement("animation_state");
        Element sequence = testDoc.createElement("animation_sequence");
        testDoc.getElementsByTagName("animations_list").item(0).appendChild(animationState).appendChild(state);
        testDoc.getElementsByTagName("animation_state").item(testDoc.getElementsByTagName("state").getLength() - 1).appendChild(sequence);
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(testDoc);
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream("./data/sprite_types/" + spriteName + "/" + spriteName + ".xml");
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(ps);
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(source, result);
```

[image: not good]
[image: good]

Comment: So the first thing I've noticed - 'sequence' is misspelled on the closing tag.

Comment: That's was a typo on my part, just to prove how I wish it to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you're creating the `animation_sequence` element but not creating any child node under it. Effectively, you are creating an empty element. Empty elements, when serialized to string, will always appear as `<tag/>`, rather than `<tag></tag>`.

To avoid this, you need to add an empty `Text` node as a child node of the `animation_sequence` element:

```
sequence.appendChild(testDoc.createTextNode(""));
```

(Or, if you use Commons Lang, replace `""` with `StringUtils.EMPTY`)

Comment: I tried doing what you said right before I append sequence, and after I append it, and I still have the same problem.

Comment: Argh, I just realized now by adding the "" nothing happens, but by adding " " an extra space is now in my state, so for example, yahoo became "yahoo "